# onblur name field

Tags: javascript

I can't seem to find a way to get the javascript to take the inputted name I put in the box to make it appear where the paragraph is as output when the onblur event happens.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<!--

INFX1606 - Starter kit for Assignment 5.

-->



    <head>

        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="author" content="Joey Fultz">
        <meta name="description" content="Assignment 5">

        <title>First Swing at Javascript</title>

        <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" />

        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/scripts.js"></script>

    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="all">
            <div class="title">
                <h2>Javascript</h2>
            </div>

            <div>
                <h3>Name and Banner</h3>
            </div>
            <span>
                <label for="namebanner">Name:</label>
                <input type="text" id="namebanner" name="namefield" onblur="showname() value">
            </span>
            <p id="p1"></p>
        </div>







    </body>
</html>

function showname() {
    var x = document.getElementById("namebanner");
    x.value = x.value.to("p1");
}
```

I want to know why my javascript is wrong and why it won't show my name when the onblur event happens.

Comment: Quoting is messed up here `onblur="showname() value"`. `value` should be outside the quotes.  And what defines that function `.to()`?

Comment: We assume you have wrapped the function def in a `<script>` tag

Comment: i was trying to find the proper way to take whatever name i type and transfer it into the paragraph i have right below my span.

Answer (score 1):

This is quite easily done with JQuery

```
<input type="text" id="namebanner" name="namefield" />

<script>
    $(function(){
        $('#namebanner').blur(function(){
            $('#p1').text( $(this).val() );
        });
    });
</script>
```

or in plain javascript

```
<script>
    function showname(){
        var x = document.getElementById("namebanner");
        document.getElementById("p1").innerHTML = x.value;
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Can't use jquery it isn't allowed